# How to include a division inside a image tag in HTML?

Tags: css, html, image, division

I am at the end of a project. I have written a lot of lines of `CSS` code and adding the images to a class/id would mean editing a lot of code that I have written. It would be better if a division is added inside a image tag in `HTML`.

Hence my question is: How to include a division inside a image tag in `HTML`?

Pseudo selectors might work for me but how do I do it with Pseudo selectors?

If you are not able to solve it, have a look at this link where I have used a different approach:

[Make division image responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853803/make-division-image-responsive?lq=1)

Comment: what browsers do you need to support? Could you use pseudo selectors? (>=IE8) http://caniuse.com/#search=before

Comment: I need to support IE,opera,safari,google chrome and all touch mobile devices,It is a theme for wordpress hence i cannot compromise on the browser support

Comment: What is the minimum version of IE you need to support?

Comment: @seemly please check the above comment.

Comment: it's impossible to add a child element to an image tag as it is self closing. If you could have used pseudo selectors, you could have avoided the ball-ache of rewriting a lot of code. As it stands, you cannot avoid this issue. Maybe post an image of the desired effect and what you have currently, and see if anyone has any thoughts on way's around the issue?

Comment: I can't exactly understand what you need to do. Do you want to split an image to show part of it here and part of it there?

Comment: No i want to include a jquery function of a slideshow inside the image.<div id="slider"> is what i would be adding into the image

Comment: Can't u just position the DIV over the image?

Comment: That would be very difficult to do considering the code and the javascript and php i am using. The pseudo selectors might work.However i am not sure how they work and their support

Comment: @seemly could you please guide me with the pseudo selectors.

Comment: What if instead of using an `img` element you use a `div` and assign the image as the background? Then you could have a `div` nested inside of an image... Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well @DrydenLong i am using bootstrap,php,javscript etc. Hence it would be really difficult to do that. I did try it out but the image does not scale on different devices.

Comment: @user3274745 It is still not clear to me what you want to achieve or what the final markup needs to look like for the use with your jQuery function. An image, as a replaced inline element cannot have any child elements. And what do you mean by "pseudo selectors"? Do you mean "pseudo classes" and their selectors? If so, I cannot see how this should help you out. My guess is that you most likely made a mistake and that you have to rewrite this part of your code.

Comment: Well @Netsurfer i want to add an image as a background to a slider. Now when i do that with a division get this  error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853803/make-background-image-responsive-on-bootstrap . Now a shortcut would be to use the division inside a image hence the question

Comment: @user3274745 Sorry, I still don't fully understand your problem/ question. So what kind of element is the "slider"? And you want to add an image to this element as CSS background-image? And please forget about anything like "inside an image" - there is no "inside" an image. Would be most helpful if you would post your current HTML markup to show your problem and to make your question more clearly.

Comment: Alright here you go the website: http://oneapptheme.github.io. Did you follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853803/make-background-image-responsive-on-bootstrap

Comment: @user3274745 Yes, I did. So the two questions here are mainly one, as they both have to do with the same problem! Would have been better if you stayed in the first one. And also you got already three answers on the other question. Did none of them solve your problem?

Comment: None of them worked. You see the images are large below 380px unless img-respoinsive is added where it gets disturbed. Forget the img-responsive all i want is the image to occupy 100% of the width and become smaller below 380px

Comment: Open the website on your mobile phone and you'll get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to not have all the things in the comments I post an answer.

The "problem" on screen-/ viewport widths of 380px and below has several issues.

On your outer `<div>` with the class `slider-wrapper3` (it's the one which holds the iPhone as background image) you should use the following in your CSS:

```
.slider-wrapper3 {
   background-size: contain; /* you use cover */
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   /* keep the rest of your actual code */
}
```

and remove the width setting (`width: 310px;`) at least for your small screen layout!

By doing so you have then fixed the position and size of the container (and also the background image).

So you still need to adjust the image sizes (probably in your slider script, or wherever the image's dimensions come from).

Comment: 22 hours later i'll award you the bounty

Comment: Add your answer here too i'll give you a bounty there too:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853803/make-division-image-responsive

Comment: @user3274745 Thanks a lot. I am glad I could help you to solve your problem. I am no "bounty hunter" ;-). So I think it would be better if you post your own answer to the other question, describing what the problem was and how you solved it. You can also add a link to this question here. Then go and accept your own answer there. By doing so other users visiting the thread in the future might get the answer they are looking for ...!

Comment: I followed the instruction and done. Thanks a lot again i had worked a whole day on it.