# Make division image responsive

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am stuck in making images inside background of a class responsive.The website [url](http://oneapptheme.github.io) .

It would be very helpful if you could help me out i am using bootstrap and nivo slider.
The css and the html that i am using for the slider are given below.

The css:

```
   .slider-wrapper { 
     width: 310px; 
     height: 650px;
     background: url("images/iPhone.png") center center ;
     background-size:cover;
    }

    .nivoSlider {
      position:relative;
      width:290px;
      height:512px;
      top:60px;
      bottom:65px;
      left:23px;
      right:24px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nivoSlider img {
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      width:100%;
      height: 100%
    }
```

The html:

```
    <div class="slider-wrapper ">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

    <img src=""  />
    <img src=""  />
    </div>
    </div>
```

And a screenshot of the above code (with additional html ) on a laptop:

[image]

Here is the website [url](http://oneapptheme.github.io). Try viewing it below 380px width as that's when the problem occurs.
I want the image to be visible properly at less than 380px.

I want the all the images to become smaller and be in the center and properly aligned below 380px but i get this:

[image].

I would be more than thankful if you could help me out

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Ok.@Ranveer wait a minute

Comment: @Ranveer have a look at the question again

Comment: Do you want the background images in the DIVs to resize with their DIVs or just want to make the DIVs responsive?

Comment: @Ruskin have a look at the screen shot. I want the iPhone above to become smaller when screen size is reduced but the image inside should be also correctly adjusted

Comment: @user3274745 If you want image to be responsive, just use `<img src="" class="img-responsive">`. Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @Ranveer img-responsive doesn't work when tested on mobile devices have a look at the above screenshots

Comment: Do not use height and width to 100%; It can't be done. Instead use width to 100% and height to auto.

Comment: Thanks @MentalRay let me try

Comment: Didn't work @MentalRay

Comment: What version of nivo slider are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 3.2

Comment: So the slider it self is responsive? You just need the background (the phone) to move with it?

Comment: Can you put together a jsFiddle of what you have so far?

Comment: Hi apaul i am working on a live link. I'll submit a link  within an hour

Comment: Yes exactly @apaul34208

Comment: Hi everyone here is the url of the website http://oneapptheme.github.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer.It was posted to me by a user.So I'm sharing it if anyone else gets into any trouble:

"So to not have all the things in the comments I post an answer.

The "problem" on screen-/ viewport widths of 380px and below has several issues.

On your outer `<div>` with the class `slider-wrapper3` (it's the one which holds the iPhone as background image) you should use the following in your CSS:

```
.slider-wrapper3 {
   background-size: contain; /* you use cover */
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   /* keep the rest of your actual code */
}
```

and remove the width setting (`width: 310px;`) at least for your small screen layout!

By doing so you have then fixed the position and size of the container (and also the background image).

So you still need to adjust the image sizes (probably in your slider script, or wherever the image's dimensions come from)."

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to debug without seeing the whole picture, but I think you need to be using max-widths like the code below. This will prevent your divs/images from becoming larger than you want, but will allow them to be smaller if necessary.

```
.slider-wrapper { 
     max-width: 310px; 
     max-height: 650px;
     background: url("images/iPhone.png") center center ;
     background-size:cover;
    }

    .nivoSlider {
      position:relative;
      max-width:290px;
      max-height:512px;
      top:60px;
      bottom:65px;
      left:23px;
      right:24px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nivoSlider img {
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      max-width:100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Should i remove the img-responsive when i apply the above code?

Comment: Hi i still get the same error. Please have a look at the new screenshot

Comment: Not seeing a new screenshot... any change you can provide a link to what you're working on?

Comment: Can you provide a link? It's difficult to see exactly what you're trying to achieve in static screenshots.

Comment: I want the .slider-wrapper to stretch to full width without the child elements being affected at width less than 380px

Comment: Sorry user, I'll need to see a link to help you further.

Comment: Your answer was the best one available though you didn't follow up. Here's the bounty i have found the answer and posted it

Comment: I did look at the link, but it seemed to be working OK so I thought you'd figured it out already. Glad it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioned elements need to be put in a floated container to move responsively. The mobile content will move in sync with the screen shell if you put the absolute container into a floated one. I ran into this exact same problem on one of my projects - it's a surprisingly easy solution.

Pen:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/tFhkz

Note the pink absolute positioned element moves as you resize the screen while staying inline with the blue box. The whole blue box with the pink absolutely positioned element inside will float together as unit to any width.

HTML:

```
  <div class="hero-background">  
    <div class="hero-text-area-container">
      <h3 class="hero-text-effects">Eaters: Find Your Favorite Food Truck</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="iphone-backdrop">
        <div class="hero-image-band-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS (background colors are to show elements):

```
.hero-background {
background: #dedede;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 4em;
min-height: 20em;
min-width: 100%;
}

.hero-text-area-container {
background: #d6ffd1;
float: left;
margin: 0% 6%;
max-height: 25em;
padding-top: 11em;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 55%;
}

.hero-background .hero-text-area-container h3 {
background: #f7f7f2;
opacity: .8;
padding: 1em;
text-align: center;
}

.iphone-backdrop {
background: #d1e2ff;
float: left;
height: 120px;
max-width: 320px;
padding-top: 2em;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
}

.hero-image-band-container {
background: #ffd1d1;
height: 80px;
position: absolute;
width: 80px;
top: 13%;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out how your code runs. Though it would be much appreciated if you correct my code.

Comment: @staypuffman the code is a bit confusing if there is a chance you could edit my code above  and post it as an answer.It would be much appreciated

Comment: @user3274745 - you are already using my technique! You are using the grid that has a 30px padding on .jumbotron. Once you drop that padding, you are good down to 320px. If you need that padding on larger resolutions, make a custom media query to drop the padding at a certain breakpoint of your choosing and you should be good here.

Comment: Well @staypuftman its not the padding.It's the image that is causing the error.I want .slider-wrapper to occupy 100% of the width at less than 380px but  .nivoSlider img and .nivoslider i don't know how to arrange them.

Comment: Then you just need a media query at 380px that takes nivoSlider to width:100% and hides the .nivoslider container. You cant do what you are saying without a media query.

Answer (score 0):

Change the css in `nivo-slider.css` from:

```
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

To

```
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;

/* now this is the important things for your problem */
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media(max-width: 380px) {
.nivoSlider{
position:relative;
width:94%;
height:378px;
top:85px;
bottom:0px;
left:8px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```