# Css positioning of parent and child elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please try this url where i have explained the problem in more detail:[Make division image responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853803/make-division-image-responsive)

I want to make the width of .slider-wrapper 100%. How do i change the other components of the css?
      The css:

```
 .slider-wrapper { 
     width: 310px; 
     height: 650px;
     background: url("images/iPhone.png") center center ;
     background-size:cover;
    }

    .nivoSlider {
      position:relative;
      width:290px;
      height:512px;
      top:60px;
      bottom:65px;
      left:23px;
      right:24px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nivoSlider img {
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      width:100%;
      height: 100%
    }
```

The html:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper ">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

    <img src=""  />
    <img src=""  />
    </div>
    </div>
```

The image:

[image]

I would really appreciate if you could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use !important like this

```
.nivoSlider {
      position:relative;
      width:290px !important;
      height:512px;
      top:60px;
      bottom:65px;
      left:23px;
      right:24px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

or you must define it better like this

```
.nivoSlider slider-wrapper {
      position:relative;
      width:290px;
      height:512px;
      top:60px;
      bottom:65px;
      left:23px;
      right:24px;
      }
```

Comment: You must type it without the *

Comment: What about .slider-wrapper should i change the width to 100%

Comment: Have a look at the website http://oneapptheme.github.io. When below 380px e.g on an iPhone the images are large enough i want the the images with all the divisions to become smaller and occupy 100% of the width. Open the website below 380px. You'll get it

Comment: Answer the question and i'll give you a bounty

Comment: Open the website on your mobile phone and you'll get it

Comment: Please try this url where i have explained the problem in more detail:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853803/make-division-image-responsive